# Lists are not showing in RecyclerView, whenever searching on Search Filter in Android Kotiln

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to search for a list in a RecyclerView in Kotlin. The problem is, list is not filtering inside the recycler view when I search for any text. Maybe there is an issue in the adapter.
    Below, these are the classes

**TenderListActivity**

**This page is having RecyclerView, SearchView**

```
    public lateinit var adapter: ListTenderAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAvailabletenderBinding
    private val viewModel: NotificationViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationViewModel::class.java)
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_availabletender)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<FragmentAvailabletenderBinding>(
            this,
            R.layout.fragment_availabletender
        )

        initViewModel()
        setupSort()
        setupRecyclerView()
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() {

        binding.tenderList.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(5))
        adapter = ListTenderAdapter((ListTenderAdapter.OnClickListener {
            viewModel.displayPropertyDetails(it)
        }),viewModel.response.value!!)

        binding.tenderList.setAdapter(adapter)

     }

    private fun initViewModel() {
        viewModel.response.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })
    }


    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    private fun setupSort() {

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.array_name1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        binding.spinner1.setAdapter(adapter)

        binding.spinner1.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                adapterView: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View,
                position: Int,
                l: Long
            ) {
                if (position == 1) {
                    sortById()
                } else {
                    sortByPrice()
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sortById() {
        viewModel.sortById.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })
    }

    private fun sortByPrice() {
        viewModel.sortByPrice.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        Log.d("call","searchView")

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)
                return true
            }
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
        return true
    }
}
```

**NotificationViewModel
    Here the response is getting**

```
    private val _sortByPrice = MutableLiveData<List<TenderProperty>>()

    val sortByPrice: LiveData<List<TenderProperty>>
        get() = _sortByPrice

    private val _sortById = MutableLiveData<List<TenderProperty>>()

    val sortById: LiveData<List<TenderProperty>>get() = _sortById

 // The external immutable LiveData for the response String
    private val _response = MutableLiveData<List<TenderProperty>>()
    val response: LiveData<List<TenderProperty>>
        get() = _response

    private val _navigateToSelectedProperty = MutableLiveData<TenderProperty>()
    val navigateToSelectedProperty: LiveData<TenderProperty>
        get() = _navigateToSelectedProperty

    private var viewModelJob = Job()


    init {
        getTenderRealEstateProperties()
    }

    private fun getTenderRealEstateProperties() {

        coroutineScope.launch {
            // Get the Deferred object for our Retrofit request
            var getPropertiesDeferred = TenderApi.retrofitService.getProperties()
            try {
                // this will run on a thread managed by Retrofit
                val listResult = getPropertiesDeferred.await()

                _sortByPrice.value=listResult.toList().sortedBy {it.price}
                _sortById.value=listResult.toList().sortedBy {it.id}

                _response.value = listResult
                println("hii"+_response.value)
                Log.d("class","_response.value")

            } catch (e: Exception) {

                _response.value = ArrayList()
                Log.d("class","_response.value")
            }
        }
    }

    fun displayPropertyDetails(marsProperty: TenderProperty) {
        _navigateToSelectedProperty.value = marsProperty
    }

    /**
     * After the navigation has taken place, make sure navigateToSelectedProperty is set to null
     */
    fun displayPropertyDetailsComplete() {
        _navigateToSelectedProperty.value = null
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }

}
```

**ListTenderAdapter
    This is Adapter class having getFilter() method**

```
class ListTenderAdapter(private val onClickListener: OnClickListener, private val tender:List<TenderProperty>) :
    ListAdapter<TenderProperty, ListTenderAdapter.TenderPropertyViewHolder>(DiffCallback),

    Filterable {

    class TenderPropertyViewHolder(private var binding: TenderListViewBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(tenderProperty: TenderProperty) {
            binding.property = tenderProperty
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TenderProperty>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: TenderProperty, newItem: TenderProperty): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: TenderProperty, newItem: TenderProperty): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): TenderPropertyViewHolder {
        return TenderPropertyViewHolder(TenderListViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TenderPropertyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val tenderProperty = getItem(position)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onClickListener.onClick(tenderProperty)
        }
        holder.bind(tenderProperty)
    }

    class OnClickListener(val clickListener: (tenderProperty: TenderProperty) -> Unit) {
        fun onClick(tenderProperty: TenderProperty) = clickListener(tenderProperty)
    }


     override fun getFilter(): Filter {

       return object : Filter() {
               override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

                   val queryString = constraint.toString()

                   val filterResults = FilterResults()
                   filterResults.values = if (constraint.isNullOrBlank()) {
                       tender
                   }
                   else
                       tender.filter {
                                   it.id.contains(queryString) ||
                                   it.imgSrcUrl.contains(queryString) ||
                                   it.price.toString().contains(queryString)
                           }
                   return filterResults
               }

               override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                   results?.values as List<TenderProperty>?
                   notifyDataSetChanged()
               }
           }
       } }
```

**TenderProperty This is the Modal class**

```
data class TenderProperty(

    val id: String,
    // used to map img_src from the JSON to imgSrcUrl in our class
    @Json(name = "img_src") val imgSrcUrl: String,
    val type: String,
    val price: Double
)
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to change val to var in your constructor.

```
private var tender:List<TenderProperty>
```

I think the problem is you have to set again list in publishResults() method.

```
tender.clear()
tender.addAll(results?.values as List<TenderProperty>?)
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

**Note**: you have to use deep copy list of tender list. Because, in this scenario original list will be filtered and you can't get original list after clear the filter.

Comment: I added these lines but the following Exception is showing.

Comment: **Caused by: Kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.bitcomm.main.TenderListActivity.setupRecyclerView(TenderListActivity.kt:50)
        at com.bitcomm.main.TenderListActivity.onCreate(TenderListActivity.kt:42)**

Comment: **private fun setupRecyclerView() {

        binding.tenderList.addItemDecoration(MarginItemDecoration(5))
        adapter = ListTenderAdapter((ListTenderAdapter.OnClickListener {
            viewModel.displayPropertyDetails(it)
        }),viewModel.response.value!!)

        binding.tenderList.setAdapter(adapter)

     }**

Comment: @AnishSethiya Try to remove `return filterResults` from else statement after added these lines